# converting text in textbox to decimal format

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have Textbox which takes decimal values. I have written Keypress event to enter decimal numbers. But when I am trying to convert the value in the textbox to Decimal format to store in database, it is only converting it to Integer.

I am trying to convert text to decimal as follows:

```
dr["Total Amount"] = Decimal.Parse(txtTotalAmount.Text.ToString());
```

well I am using the above code with the `datagridview`.

Comment: What's the datatype of the field in your database table which holds that value ??

Comment: what is the string value of textbox?

Comment: @Yogi: The data type in the database table is decimal(18, 0).

Comment: @AppDeveloper: Iam giving a value ex:120.75 in the textbox

Comment: how about showing what the value of txtTotalAmount.Text looks like Varun so you can get a more accurate answer...

Comment: Can u please tell what is the datatype in your DataSet?

Comment: Because the type of the `Text` property is `string`, calling `.ToString()` on that value only increases clutter in your code.

Comment: @kakarott why would Convert.ToDecimal be better than Decimal.Parse?  I would argue that it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly check your `DataType` of **Total Amount** in your table. if you are using SQL Server and want to store decimal value then you have to use [money](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx) or [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) according to your need. 
Note: `DECIMAL(2,2)` and `DECIMAL(2,4)` are different data types. This means that 11.22 and 11.2222

Comment: The data type in the database table is decimal(18, 0)

Comment: it sould have been decimal(18, 2)